# Who should our beta moderators be?

Tags: discussion, 7-questions, moderators

For details of who was appointed, see the [Moderator Pro Tem Announcement](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/124/164).

---

Since *Sustainable Living* Stack Exchange has now gone into public beta, soon it will be time for us to get our first crop of moderators, as explained in the [“Moderator Pro Tempore” blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/):

> About a week into the public beta, we will seek out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:
>
> - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
> - Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
> - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
> - Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [*A Theory of Moderation*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Each beta site has (approximately) three moderators on a temporary, short-term appointment. Moderators Pro Tem focus and expedite the essential needs of each new site, both in terms of [regular moderator activies](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) and as a liaison of the growing community with the Stack Exchange team. By the end of Beta, the community will be better suited to hold their own elections.

Although the moderators pro tempore will ultimately be selected by Stack Exchange, the purpose of this post is to seek out and propose candidates:

- Each nomination should be posted as an answer and it should include (at minimum) a link to the user's main and meta profile so we can check out their activity.
- Self nominations are encouraged, step up if you feel you can help.
- If you are nominated by someone else you should edit the answer and let us know if you accept or decline (explanation optional). If a nominee declines we will not delete the answer, as to not have someone else nominate them again.
- If you are nominating someone else, please mark the post as Community Wiki before saving. Meta doesn't allow suggested edits, so your nominee may be blocked from accepting the nomination.
- The nominations are not binding to Stack Exchange or the nominees. If you are being considered by Stack Exchange, you will get an official confirmation email at one point.
- Before nominating someone or accept / decline a nomination, you should read [*A Theory of Moderation*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) thoroughly to find out what's generally expected from moderators.

If you would like to learn more about the role, please drop into [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7310/sustainable-living) where you can ask about the role from other moderators (they appear with a blue name in the chat room). Another chatroom called [The Assembly](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2691/the-assembly) was created specifically for users and moderators to discuss moderation activities, moderators from all over the network are there to answer your questions.

Once again, **please don't hesitate to step up and self-nominate!**.

<sup>To give credit, this is pretty much copied from a similar question on [Robotics meta](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/84/37), which was based on the one on [Chemistry meta](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/113).</sup>

Answer (score 9):

This post is both a nomination and an example of a nomination to get the rest of you started. *8')

---

I would like to nominate *EnergyNumbers* ([Sustainability](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/48/energynumbers) | [Sustainability meta](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/users/48/energynumbers) | [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/users/339125/energynumbers)), for the position of *Moderator Pro Tempore*:

[image: EnergyNumbers:1430, gold:0, silver:3, bronze:20] [image: EnergyNumbers:1430, gold:0, silver:0, bronze:12] [EnergyNumbers:15k, gold:1, silver:46, bronze:250 http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/339125.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/339125.png)

*EnergyNumbers* has been active both on the main site and here on *meta*, currently with the highest level of *meta* participation and 4th highest overall reputation on the main site.

*EnergyNumbers* has also shown an inclination to help people directly by taking issues to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7310/sustainable-living) rather than cluttering up answers or comments with inappropriate asides.

---

#### Added by EnergyNumbers

I'd be happy to take on the temporary role of moderator, so please do add me into the pool of candidates under consideration.

I wish I had more ideas for promoting the site. I do the things I've thought of: I link to questions on Twitter; I circulate questions (and links to them) to mailing lists when they're directly relevant; I add links from [my blog](http://energynumbers.info/?apsref=meta.sust.SE). Given that neither I nor anyone else has earnt [an Announcer badge for Sustainability.SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/badges/59/announcer) yet, I guess none of us have got any traction yet. I'll keep trying different things.

My vision for the site is one that is quite broad: a superset of the lifestyle stuff; my own interests are at the macro level (decarbonisation at the national / global levels), rather than the micro. That's quite a way from where the Area51 proposal started, but I think it's consistent with where the site is now.

Comment: While I haven't been active on SL.SE, from the lens of Physics.SE and Chem.SE, EnergyNumbers is a good candidate. He (she?) is active in community moderation, as well as in the [renewable energy](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:4066+[renewable-energy]) tag on Physics. +1

Answer (score 6):

I would like to nominate *Chris Travers* ([Sustainability](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/130) | [Sustainability meta](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/users/130) | [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/users/1750416/energynumbers)), for the position of *Moderator Pro Tempore*:

[image: Chris Travers:2628, gold:0, silver:2, bronze:14] [image: Chris Travers:2628, gold:0, silver:0, bronze:3] [Chris Travers:12k, gold:1, silver:13, bronze:86 http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1750416.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1750416.png)

*Chris Travers* has been active both on the main site and here on *meta*.

---

*Chris Travers* please indicate whether you would like to accept or decline this nomination by editing this section. You may also want to write more about yourself. *8')

Answer (score 5):

I would like to nominate *Jay Bazuzi* ([Sustainability](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/27) | [Sustainability meta](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/users/27) | [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/users/3669/energynumbers)), for the position of *Moderator Pro Tempore*:

[image: Jay Bazuzi:1603, gold:0, silver:2, bronze:16] [image: Jay Bazuzi:1603, gold:0, silver:0, bronze:4] [Jay Bazuzi:39k, gold:6, silver:118, bronze:359 http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/3669.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/3669.png)

*Jay Bazuzi* has been active both on the main site and here on *meta*.

---

*Jay Bazuzi* please indicate whether you would like to accept or decline this nomination by editing this section. You may also want to write more about yourself. *8')

Answer (score 3):

I would like to nominate *lechlukasz* ([Sustainability](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/5) | [Sustainability meta](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5) | [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/users/253331/energynumbers)), for the position of *Moderator Pro Tempore*:

[image: lechlukasz:861, gold:0, silver:4, bronze:16] [image: lechlukasz:861, gold:0, silver:0, bronze:4] [lechlukasz:14k, gold:3, silver:52, bronze:229 http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/253331.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/253331.png)

*lechlukasz* has been active both on the main site and here on *meta*.

---

*lechlukasz* please indicate whether you would like to accept or decline this nomination by editing this section. You may also want to write more about yourself. *8')

Answer (score 3):

I would like to nominate *user1205935* ([Sustainability](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/85) | [Sustainability meta](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/users/85) | [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/users/1244118)), for the position of *Moderator Pro Tempore*:

[image: user1205935:1141, gold:0, silver:3, bronze:20] [image: user1205935:1151, gold:0, silver:0, bronze:1] [user1205935:9.9k, gold:1, silver:11, bronze:69 http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1244118.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1244118.png)

*user1205935* has been active both on the main site and here on *meta*. Additionally *user1205935* is one of the [top reviewers](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats) on this site.

---

Thank you for the nomination. I accept the nomination. With 92 visits per day, this site is still very young and I would enjoy helping it grow, preferably into a site that addresses both the design and practical aspects of sustainable living.

Comment: Could I suggest that a name which is a little easier to remember might be more appropriate if *user1205935* wants to accept this nomination.

Comment: @MarkBooth I think a name change is a reasonable request. I will try to think about a name.

Comment: Thanks @user1205935, I know it's a bit of an imposition to ask, but the default user names are rather impersonal. *8')

Comment: Hey, uh, @user1205935 - if you're interested in doing this, I'd love it if you responded to my email...

Comment: @Shog9 I checked my email account and couldn't find an email from you anywhere... I double-checked the address in my profile as well. Could you send it again, please?

Comment: Re-sent, @user1205935 - let me know if that's MIA as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to nominate *THelper* ([Sustainability](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/99) | [Sustainability meta](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/users/99) | [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/users/384624)), for the position of *Moderator Pro Tempore*:

[image: THelper:948, gold:0, silver:3, bronze:25] [image: THelper:948, gold:0, silver:0, bronze:6] [THelper:8.5k, gold:1, silver:34, bronze:164 http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/384624.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/384624.png)

*THelper* has been active both on the main site and here on *meta*.

---

**THelper's answer**:
Thank you for the nomination! I would love to be a temporary moderator, but there is one problem. Our second child will be born in a couple of weeks, so when that happens I'll probably want to spend my spare time catching up on sleep rather than moderating this site. 
However, I really care for sustainability and very much want this site to flourish. I also read [this post about the lack of people that are willing to moderate](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/114/99). If we cannot find enough moderators in, let's say two weeks, I will accept the nomination after all and hope I don't fall asleep behind my computer too often ;-)

**UPDATE:** It seems like there are not enough people willing to be a temp moderator, and Mark Booth mentioned that being a mod probably won't require much time at first, so I've decided to accept the nomination after all.

Comment: BTW, I don't visit meta very often and wasn't aware of this post until just now. I can imagine that other nominees don't visit meta often as well. Can the nominees be notified about this post?

Comment: @THelper - Don't worry, the community mod team will take all of this into account when they invite people to be protems. Also, if *Sustainability* is as slow burn as *Robotics* (which looks likely) then there may be only a few flags to handle every week between the protem moderators.

Comment: Did you get the email invitation a few weeks back, @THelper?

Comment: @Shog9 Yes, I did get an email from Anna Lear about 6 weeks ago. I turned down the offer at the time for the same reasons stated above, but that was before I knew you had trouble finding enough moderators. It seems like we currently only have 2 people willing to be a temp moderator and if I'm not mistaken a site usually has 3 moderators, so I've decided to accept the nomination after all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for moderators, I would like to volunteer. I believe I have suitable experience and knowledge and love sharing and hearing about others ideas.

I live off grid, and are 100% self sufficient in power and water supply. I am currently designing our aquaponics system to provide at least 50% of our food requirements for our family of 5.

I have designed and installed our solar solution myself, and have built our house, along with my wife without the help of any contractors.

We reuse 100% of the water we use, on our kitchen gardens, and blend our humanure with our food and green waste to fertilize the garden.

Comment: Sorry Jason, but you were too late, moderators have [already been appointed](http://meta.sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/124/164) for now.

Comment: Nevertheless you (and all other users for that matter) are welcome to help out and improve this site. High quality questions and answers are very important and will help attract more people to this site. People who have enough [reputation](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/privileges) can also help by [reviewing](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/review) and improving posts, writing tag wikis, and [flagging](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/privileges/flag-posts) inappropriate posts. There is a lot to do before this site comes out of beta and we all have to do this together.