# Moderators needed

Tags: discussion, moderators

we have a problem: we can't find enough folks willing to moderate this site.

That's... ***Kind of a bad sign.***

#### Background

Every site needs people to handle moderation duties. While most of this can be done by folks using the site, there are a few tasks that [require special privileges](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/):

> Even with active community self-regulation, moderators occasionally need to intervene. Moderators are human exception handlers, there to deal with those (hopefully rare) exceptional conditions that should not normally happen, but when they do, they can bring your entire community to a screaming halt — if you don’t have human exception handling in place.

Initially, we (employees of Stack Exchange) act as moderators on a site. But a few weeks after a site enters public beta, we'll start looking for folks who would make good moderators and contacting them to see if they're willing to be [Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) until the site has grown enough to allow for elections.

Sometimes, this happens quickly - the first few people we email respond and we're done. Sometimes, it takes a bit longer. But at this point, we're over *two months* and only have one volunteer (moderator teams are normally at least three people strong).

We kinda *need* mods here. At least a couple. If we can't get that, it's, well... [Kind of a bad sign](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/).

If you're interested and qualified, volunteer here: [Who should our beta moderators be?](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62/who-should-our-beta-moderators-be)

Answer (score 3):

I think that often people are unwilling to nominate themselves for fear that no-one will consider them a good candidate.

So to save people from themselves I have taken the liberty of going through the top meta contributors who are also strong contributors to the main site and added a few more nominations:

- [Chris Travers](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/a/116/164)
- [Jay Bazuzi](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/a/117/164)
- [lechlukasz](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/a/118/164)
- [THelper](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/a/115/164)

to add to my original nomination of [EnergyNumbers](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/a/79/164).

This should in no way discourage people from nominating themselves. I'm sure that people would much rather someone who wanted the job got it rather than someone who felt press-ganged into service.

On a side note, I've found the opportunity to be Moderator Pro tempore on [Robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/) has given me a fascinating insight into the way Stack Exchange works under the covers and I have been honoured to be able to help nurture *Robotics* and help it grow.