# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The [first full moderator election](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/election/2) on Sustainable Living has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the winners are:

[image: Robotnik]

[image: LShaver]

[image: Nic]

Robotnik will be joining [the existing crew](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly, and congrats to LShaver and Nic for being reelected — please thank them for volunteering!

Also, please join me in thanking the following user, who will be stepping down as moderator:

[image: THelper]

[THelper has been a moderator since the site went into beta in 2013](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/124/5864) – thanks to them for the 9 years they spent helping improve the site!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6230843478507520).

Comment: Congrats to all the elected moderators!

Answer (score 4):

Congrats **Robotnik**, and welcome to the team! Looking forward to working with you!

**THelper**, thanks for all your contributions as moderator these last 9 years(!), and enjoy your retirement!