# Upcoming moderator election in January 2023

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

Sustainable Living Stack Exchange [last had moderators elected around half a year ago](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/410/2143). After discussing it with the current moderator team, we're looking at scheduling an election to start sometime in January 2023, in response to some members of the team having stepped down from the position, and the moderation team being below our minimum of 3 mods per team as a result.

**It should be noted that having folks willing to step up and moderate the sites is one of the few requirements we have for keeping sites alive,** and given that we *need* to schedule an election (to bring the moderation team up to the minimum of 3 members), should it fail we'll need to have a discussion about the site's future.

But that's getting ahead of ourselves right now: to avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, I'm posting this now to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves when the actual election's nomination period starts.

**Please post an answer below if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position. As I mentioned, we're looking at scheduling the nomination period to start sometime in January 2023.**

**NOTE:** This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to include your whole election nomination statement.

**What do diamond moderators do?**

Broadly speaking, moderators handle things out of the ordinary. These include processing flags, issuing suspensions, acting as a point of contact between staff and the community, investigating vote fraud, and managing disputes, among other things. You can read more at [A Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) on the Stack Overflow Blog for a general overview.

**What do we expect of moderators?**

From looking at the moderator dashboard, the moderation workload isn't huge on Sustainable Living. A few minutes a day should be enough time to dedicate to moderator activities. In terms of temperament, we're generally looking for people who can communicate well, keep their cool, and evaluate things from an objective standpoint. Having a decent grasp of the subject matter is a definite plus, as well as having previously shown involvement in the moderation and upkeep of the site (such as helping with the review queues and flagging).

Comment: Some of the text was adapted from [this post on AI.SE](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2902/45).